# Passing variable length argument list to AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive I'm using for disabling buttons while I'm doing some behind the scenes work (to avoid getting double submits): http://jsfiddle.net/7nA3S/6/

I would like to be able to extend this so that the directive attribute can accept functions with arbitrary length argument lists.

I know the usual angular way is to just assign the values you need to other attributes on the element, but I'm wondering if there's a good way to generalize this. i could maybe do something like

`<button my-submit='someFunction' args="arg1, arg2, arg3, ...">No Evals<button>`

and then split up the args string, but maybe there's a less cruddy way?

Comment: Are the args references or ids of other buttons you want to disable? Or are you just trying to pass lots of args to `$scope.myAsyncSubmit()`?

Comment: the function that gets called might take anything. not necessarily lots of args, just an arbitrary number. the case i'm currently trying to solve for is a function `searchOrders` that takes an integer and a boolean. the idea is that the directive shouldn't know anything about `myAsyncSubmit`, other than that it returns a promise and that it takes a given set of params.

Comment: `searchOrders` is comparable to `myAsyncSubmit`

Comment: using the word submit is a misnomer. i'll revise the fiddle.

Comment: Okay I think I get it - why don't those params go in the main controller, and when the directive invokes `myAsyncSubmit` it gets its args from the same `$scope` as itself?

Comment: i'm not sure where the values would get set in the controller, since their values depend on context in the template.

Comment: wait, in the directive template? I think I would reconsider using a directive for that. I think the directive is only supposed to be responsible for disabling/enabling buttons as the promise resolves, right?

Comment: sorry @willoller, i should have articulated more clearly. The values passed are dependent on their location in the *page* template. For example, I might want to have a separate button for each different order I want to "search".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7nA3S/7/ .

You can use `ng.$parse` to evaluate the function with the arguments you have provided against the given `$scope`.

You then can get the arguments passed to the function from the `arguments` array inside the `$scope.myAsyncSubmit` function.

Comment: And just to elaborate, the `arguments` keyword was definitely something I forgot about, but it was your use of `ng.$parse` that truly saved the day